# Mounting user SSH key in container

Tags: ssh, docker

I am building a script that will mount some local folders into the container, one of which is the user's `~/.ssh` folder. That way, users can still utilize their SSH key for Git commits.

`docker run -ti -v $HOME/.ssh/:$HOME/.ssh repo:tag`

But that does not mount the SSH folder into the container. Am I doing it incorrectly?

Comment: the command line doesn't seem to be correct: braces, no actual command (or placeholder).

Comment: besides, according to https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/containers/dockervolumes/, your mapping is unnecessary unless you wish to _write_ to that dir and the changes to be reflected on the host.

Answer (score 0):

The typical syntax is (from [Mount a host directory as a data volume](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/containers/dockervolumes/#mount-a-host-directory-as-a-data-volume)):

```
docker run -d -P --name web -v /src/webapp:/opt/webapp training/webapp python app.py
```

(you can skip the command part, here '`app.py`', if your image defines an entrypoint and default command)
(`-d` does not apply in your case, it did in the case of that python web server )

Try:

```
docker run -ti -v $HOME/.ssh:$HOME/.ssh repo:tag
```

Comment: It's still not mounting my SSH keys and that's the exact same command I'm using...

Comment: @mynameismevin What do you see in the container, as $HOME/.ssh? Are we talking about the same $HOME?

Comment: Yes, from within the container, I was seeing `/root/.ssh/` mounted, but there was nothing inside it.

Comment: @mynameismevin That is why! We are not talking about the same HOME. Make sure your Dockerfile declares a user with the same name as the one you have on your host. That Dockerfile should include the lines `USER yourLogin` and `WORKDIR /home/yourLogin`.